# Combine GeoServer ShapeFile with WMS Basemap on a Leaflet Client

Tags: json, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I am trying to combine a WMS with an external ShapeFile uploaded to my GeoServer.
I got my WMS Map working fine with a leaflet client but I have no idea how to implement my Shapefile.
I uploaded my ShapeFile on my GeoServer in the Vectordata section.

When I do the WFS DescribeFeature request I get this answer:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:Assignment11="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Assignment11" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Assignment11">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="krankenhaeuserType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="KH_ID" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="KH_BEZ" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="KH_TELEFON" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="KH_URL" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="KH_ART" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TRAEGER" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="RECHTSFOR" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BS_BEZ" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="PLZ" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ADRESSE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ORT" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DISZIPLIN" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="BETTENZAHL" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="krankenhaeuser" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="Assignment11:krankenhaeuserType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

When I do the GetFeature Request with outputFormat=JSON (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Assignment11:krankenhaeuser&outputFormat=JSON) the answer is a complete FeatureCollection of all my features.

The thing I am missing now is that I want to add all those Features to my map as a marker for example.
Thats the main problem.
When I got that working, I want to hide all those Features and when I click the map I want the closest Feature to pop up.

This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Assignment 11</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body>



<div id="mapid" style="width: 1400px; height: 700px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.28, 7.33], 8);

    var nrwTopo = L.tileLayer.wms('http://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dtk?', {
        layers: 'WMS_NW_DTK',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    }).addTo(mymap);


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To just load a shapefile, either transform it into GeoJSON (with qgis or ogr2ogr *et al*) or have a look at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-data-formats . Look into implementations of `getFeatureInfo` on the geoserver side.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!Okay I know now how to get the XML file of all my features in my FeatureCollection with a HTTP Get request. But how do I display them on my map?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that - Do you want to use WFS? Is WFS available at all? What are the capabilities of WFS (XML/GeoJSON/etc)? Do you manage the GeoServer instance or not? Is your end goal to detect clicks on the feature area, to fetch data around a clicked point, or to fetch the nearest feature to the click? The more specificity and detail, the better. Please take your time to edit your question.

Comment: I edited my post. Hope it is a bit more clear now... Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Anyone who has got some ideas? I am stuck...

Comment: why not use the existing WMS connection? or use the Leaflet WFS - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129965/how-to-add-geoserver-wfs-to-leaflet-js-application

Comment: I cant get that to work... :-(